# Where to purchase GVB Day Tickets in Schiphol?

Tags: public-transport, netherlands, ams

Is there a map online that shows where in Schiphol Airport tickets can be purchased for the [GVB day ticket](https://en.gvb.nl/gvb-dag-meerdagenkaart)?

Answer (score 4):

The page you linked to mentions

> AKOs at Schiphol Airport

AKO is a chain of book stores, and [this page on the official Airport website](https://www.schiphol.nl/en/at-schiphol/shop/ako) lists where they are, including maps:

- [Plaza (AKO News and media), open 6am - 10pm](https://www.schiphol.nl/en/airport-maps#poi-5wavmrV9VSwsgM6Cu42siO)
- [Plaza (AKO kiosk), open 24/7](https://www.schiphol.nl/en/airport-maps#poi-362LgiZIDei8QyKwqa02UU)
- [Plaza (AKO Books and travel), open 7am - 10pm](https://www.schiphol.nl/en/airport-maps#poi-2b7AAPvjqJdcTiaMJXYA4p)